# could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(ListAlarms)" Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, alarm

I am doing an alarm app with react native. When i launch my code it gives me the following error: *"could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(ListAlarms)"
Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to  and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(ListAlarms) in connect options"*
what am I doing wrong? what is the solution?

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';
import ListAlarms from './src/components/ListAlarms';
import TimePicker from './src/components/TimePicker';

const App = () => {
    return (
      <View style = {styles.mainContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.heading}>Alarm App</Text>
          <SafeAreaView style={styles.ListAlarms}>
            <ListAlarms />
          </SafeAreaView>
          <View style={styles.TimePicker}>
            <TimePicker />
          </View>
         </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer:{
    flex:1,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  heading:{
    fontSize:25,
    padding: 20,
  },
  TimePicker:{
    paddingTop:"10%",
    width:"50%",
    bottom: 20,
  },
  ListAlarms: {
    flex: 1,
    width:"100%",
  }
});
export default App;
```

**TimePicker.js**

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  Alert
  
} from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addAlarm } from "../actions/alarms";
import DateTimePicker from 'react-native-modal-datetime-picker';


const TimePicker = (props) => {
    const [isDateTimePickerVisible, setIsDateTimePickerVisible] = useState(false);
    const makeid=()=>{
        var length = 5;
        var result = "";
        var characters="0123456789";
        var charactersLength=characters.length;
        for (vari=0; i<length; i++){
            result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() + charactersLength));
        }
        return result;

    }
    const showDateTimePicker = () => {
        setIsDateTimePickerVisible(true);
    }
    const hideDateTimePicker = () => {
        setIsDateTimePickerVisible(false);
    }
    const handleDatePicker = (datetime) => {
        var currentTime = Date.now(); 
        if(datetime.getTime() < currentTime) {
            Alert.alert("Please Choose future time");
            hideDateTimePicker();
            return;
        }
        const alarmNotifData={
            id:makeid(),
            title: "Alarms Ringing",
            message: "My Notification Message",
            channel: "alarm-channel",
            ticker:"My Notificacion Message",
            auto_canel: true,
            vibrate:true,
            vibration:100,
            small_icon:"ic_launcher",
            large_icon:"ic_launcher",
            play_sound:true,
            sound_name: null,
            color:"red",
            schedule_once:true,
            tag:"some_tag",
            fire_date:Date.now(),
            date:{ value: datetime }
        }
        props.add(alarmNotifData)
        
        hideDateTimePicker();
    }
    return(
        <>
             <Button
                    title = "+ Add Alarms"
                    color = "blue"
                    onPress = {() => {
                            showDateTimePicker();
                    }}
             >
            </Button>

             <DateTimePicker
                mode="datetime"
                isVisible={isDateTimePickerVisible}
                onConfirm={handleDatePicker}
                onCancel={hideDateTimePicker}
            />
           
        </>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps= state =>{
    return {};
}

const mapDispatchToProps= dispatch =>{
    return {
        add:alarmNotifObj=>{
            dispatch(addAlarm(alarmNotifObj));
        }
    };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(TimePicker);
```

**ListAlarms.js**

```
 import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  View,
  FlatList,

} from 'react-native';
import {ListItem} from 'react-native-elements';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { deleteAlarm } from "../actions/alarms";
import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';

const ListAlarms=(props)=>{
    const KeyExtractor =(item,index) => index.toString();
    const renderItem =  ({item}) => {
        return(
            <ListItem>
                <ListItem.Content>
                    <ListItem.Title style ={styles.titleStyle}>{item.time.toString()}</ListItem.Title>
                    <ListItem.Subtitle>{item.date.toString()}</ListItem.Subtitle>
                </ListItem.Content>
                <Button
                    title = "Remove"
                    color = "red"
                    onPress = {() => {
                        props.delete(item.value);
                    }}
                >      
                </Button>
            </ListItem>
        );
    }
    return (
        <FlatList>
            KeyExtracto={KeyExtractor}
            data={props.alarms}
            renderItem={renderItem}
        </FlatList>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    titleStyle: { fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 30 }
})


const mapStateToProps= state =>{
    return {
        alarms:state.alarms.alarms,
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps= dispatch =>{
    return {
        delete:value=>{
            dispatch(deleteAlarm(value));
        }
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(ListAlarms);
```

**index.js**

```
    import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
import App from './app.json';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import React from 'react';
import configureStore from "./src/store";

const store = configureStore();
const RNRedux=()=>{
    return <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider> 
    
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => RNRedux);


**index.js (in store folder)**

    import { createStore, combineReducers} from 'redux';

import alarmReducer from '../reducers/alarmReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    alarms: alarmReducer,

});

const configureStore=()=>{
    return createStore(rootReducer);
};

export default configureStore;
```

Comment: You just provided like 200 lines of code. Any chance you can simplify this down to just the minimum amount required to reproduce the problem?

Comment: the problem is that I don't know where specifically the error is, that's why all the lines of code are so long, honestly.

Comment: Remove stuff until the bug doesn't happen :) There's a lot of fat to cut. StackOverflow users don't need to see your styles, and probably 3/4 of the remaining code.